# Where is documentation for libattr?

Tags: c, documentation, id3

I'm trying to use libattr in a c program, and cannot find any information on how to use it.

```
[user~/src/libattr_testing]$ find / -type f 2>/dev/null | grep libattr
/lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
/usr/include/attr/libattr.h
/usr/lib/libattr.a
```

Am I missing something obvious? I've been searching for documentation or a working example but can't find a thing.

Comment: Which libattr are you talking about ? libattr on linux handles [extended file attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes), and is documented in the setxattr, attr_get, attr_list man pages - and many more. It's not about ID3 tags.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to know your libattr exactly package name then list all files in it:

For ubuntu for example

> dpkg -S /lib/libattr.so.1.1.0         //will print package name
>
> dpkg -L package_name                  //List all files in the package

then you will see a list of files in /usr/share/man directory

Answer (score 0):

libattr has nothing to do with id3-tags, it's used for ncurses. Search for id3lib instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux and want to learn about the C functions to deal with extended attributes, install the [`libattr1-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libattr1-dev) package, which has the man pages for `getxattr`, `setxattr`, etc. Or, you could view the manpages online: http://linux.die.net/man/2/getxattr